# How to make class with with variable inside of html element in Vue?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I just want to write class **`plan__part_${this.res}`** within element

````
v-bind:class="{[`plan__part_${this.res}`]: true }"
  :key="item.id"
></div>```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in following snippet your code working fine, don't use `this` in template:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      res: '1',
      item: {id: 1}
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.plan__part_1{
  background: violet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">     
  <div :class="{[`plan__part_${res}`]: true }" :key="item.id">
    {{ res }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case if your current implementation is not working then you can try using computed

```
v-bind:class="getClass"
:key="item.id"
></div>
```

and in

```
computed: {
 getClass() { 
  if(this.flag) return `plan__part_${this.res}`;
  return '';
 }
```

Note: `this.flag` is actually the boolean that you have used in the template